# Remove vowels without using too many different characters

Tags: code-challenge, string

The challenge is to remove vowels (a, e, i, o, u) from string from STDIN (yes, I know, simple). You can expect that your program will be not ran with any arguments in `argv`.

Example:

```
This program will remove VOWELS.
So we can now speak without them.
```

Is changed to:

```
Ths prgrm wll rmv VWLS.
S w cn nw spk wtht thm.
```

There is a catch. The winning entry is decided basing on number of different bytes. For example `a ab` has three different bytes (`a`, `b` and space). If two or more entries will have this same ammount of different bytes, then fallback is done on number of bytes for those entries.

Comment: A job for Whitespace language

Comment: What about input like `Renée’s naïveté`? Stripped of vowels, that should of course be  `Rn’s nvt` as output. Seem like these approaches are all pretty ahem *naïve* if you ask me. :)

Comment: If you remove é, you might want to remove y too.

Comment: @tchrist, read the question.  Says to remove a,e,i,o,u.  You're off topic, please drop it.

Comment: @boothby I did read the question. It doesn’t say what should be done with *naïve*: remember that is a six-character string with a COMBINING DIAERESIS. If you blindly strip the vowels, it sticks an umlaut on the  *n*.  Is that what is intended?

Comment: @tchrist: Especially the challenge didn't say "all vowels" **and** enumerated what we should consider as removable.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Ook would run a close second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Binary Whitespace (2 distinct chars, 324 total chars)

`TTSSSTTSSSSTTTSTTTSSSSSSTTSSSTSSSSSSTSTTSSSTSSSSTSSTSTTSSSTSSSTSSSTSTTSSSTSSSTSTSTSTSTTSSSTSSTSSTSSTSTTSSSTSTSSSSSTSTTSSSTSTSSSTSSTSTTSSSTSTSSTSSSTSTTSSSTSTSSTSTSTSTSTTSSSTSTSTSSTSSTSTTTTSSSTSTTSTTSTTTSSTSTTSSSSTTTSTSTSTSSSTSTTTSSTTTTSTTSTSTTTTSSTTTTTSSSTTTTSTTTTTTSSTSTTSSSSTTTSTSTSSTTSTTTSSSSTTTSTTSSTTSTTSTTTTSSSSTTTTTTTT`

where S,T,L denotes Space,Tab,Linefeed, respectively. (Shamelessly obtained by converting the [Whitespace answer by "breadbox"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6045/3440) into Binary Whitespace -- this posting should probably be a comment to his answer, but it's too long.)

Binary Whitespace is [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150623025348/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/) converted to a prefix-code language by everywhere using TS instead of T and using TT instead of L; e.g. the BWS instruction to push -5 onto the stack is SSTSTSSTSTT instead of SSTTSTL, etc. Link: A both-ways [translator for an arbitrary 3-symbol language and its binary prefix-code versions](https://sites.google.com/site/res0001/whitespace/programs/trans32.py) [[archive](https://github.com/wspace/res0001-trans32)].

NB: It would be straightforward to design a true *bitwise* interpreter for Binary Whitespace programs regarded as *bit*-sequences, rather than char-sequences (e.g. using 0,1 bit-values instead of S,T characters, respectively). The above would then be a 324-*bit* program requiring 41 bytes of storage.

Answer (score 13):

### Brainfuck, 8 distinct (2121 total)

```
>,+[-<>>>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>[-]+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>>[-]++<[-<+>>>>->>>->>>->>>->>>->>>->>>->>>->>>->>>-<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<>]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>[<<<]+>-[<-<.>>-]<[<<<]<[-]>,+]
```

The distict characters: [`<>+-[],.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#Commands). Works with interpreters that use `-1` for `EOF`.

> $ echo '
>   This program will remove VOWELS.
>   So we can now speak without them.
>   ' | bf vowel-rm.bf
>   
>   Ths prgrm wll rmv VWLS.
>   S w cn nw spk wtht thm.

Comment: +1 for nice language choice :). I've pretty much expected this, but...

Comment: +1 Well done! I didn't see that coming. :)

Comment: By the requirements as stated, this is the best answer; but OTOH it's the worst in that it uses *every* syntactically-significant character in its language.

Comment: That doesn’t seem to get the correct answer when supplied with `Renée’s naïveté` as input.

Comment: @tchrist: It assumes ASCII. Anyway, only {a, e, i, o, u} are in the requirements.

Comment: So it’s ok to turn `Renée’s naïveté` into `Rń’s n̈vt́`, then? That doesn’t seem right to me, but if you say so. Since you can’t assume any normalization, it is perfectly reasonable that `Renée’s naïveté` is really `"Rene\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}e\N{RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}s nai\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}vete\N{COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT}"` — or if you prefer magic numbers, `"Rene\x{301}e\x{2019}s nai\x{308}vete\x{301}"`. If you remove the vowels without their attendant diacritics, you get extreme silliness. Welcome to the Brave New Millennium! :)

Comment: Use Unary, you'd only have one distinct character! :-P http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary

Comment: @marinus, I've converted this to Unary and I just needed `1.166921663690E+1824` bytes to store it (I've uploaded [exact number](https://gist.github.com/2829412) to pastebin, it wouldn't fit in this comment). I wonder how much time it would take to send it to this site.

Answer (score 11):

### Whitespace, 3 points (218 chars)

You knew it was coming.

```
↲___↲____↲⇥↲⇥_____↲___⇥_____⇥↲___⇥___⇥_⇥↲___⇥__⇥__⇥↲___⇥__⇥⇥⇥⇥↲___⇥_⇥_⇥_⇥
↲___⇥⇥____⇥↲___⇥⇥__⇥_⇥↲___⇥⇥_⇥__⇥↲___⇥⇥_⇥⇥⇥⇥↲___⇥⇥⇥_⇥_⇥↲↲___⇥↲_↲_↲⇥_⇥↲___
_↲⇥⇥⇥⇥__⇥↲⇥_↲↲_↲_⇥↲↲__↲↲⇥__↲↲_↲↲↲__⇥↲____↲⇥⇥⇥_↲_↲⇥___↲⇥↲__↲_↲_↲↲____↲↲↲↲
```

(_ = space, ⇥ = tab, ↲ = newline)

Here's the script encoded in base64:

```
CiAgIAogICAgCgkKCSAgICAgCiAgIAkgICAgIAkKICAgCSAgIAkgCQogICAJICAJICAJCiAgIAkg
IAkJCQkKICAgCSAJIAkgCQogICAJCSAgICAJCiAgIAkJICAJIAkKICAgCQkgCSAgCQogICAJCSAJ
CQkJCiAgIAkJCSAJIAkKCiAgIAkKIAogCgkgCQogICAgCgkJCQkgIAkKCSAKCiAKIAkKCiAgCgoJ
ICAKCiAKCgogIAkKICAgIAoJCQkgCiAKCSAgIAoJCiAgCiAKIAoKICAgIAoKCgo=
```

And here's the program written in visible assembler-like form:

```
ioloop: charin  0
        push    0, 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'
ckloop: dup
        jz      out
        get     0
        sub
        jz      skip
        jump    ckloop
skip:   jz      ioloop
        jump    skip
out:    get     0
        dup
        jz      done
        charout
        jump    ioloop
done:   exit
```

Comment: Smells like [Acme::Bleach](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Acme::Bleach) to me. :)

Comment: When I convert your "symbolic" program to Whitespace, it has fatal syntax errors.

Comment: That's odd. Did you remember to remove the actual newlines before doing the conversion? I should just include a base64-encoding of the actual script.

Comment: Yes, I did that -- your base64 version decodes into exactly what I'm using. Here's an "STL" version (with S,T,L coding Space,Tab,Linefeed respectively): `LSSSLSSSLTLTSSSSLSSSTSSSSSTLSSSTSSSTSTLSSSTSSTSSTLSSSTSSTTTTLSSSTSTSTSTLSSSTTSS‌​SSTLSSSTTSSTSTLSSSTTSTSSTLSSSTTSTTTTLSSSTTTSTSTLLSSSTLSLSLTSTLSSSLTTTTSSTLTSLLSLS‌​TLLSSLLTSSLLSLLLSSTLSSSLTTTSLSLTSSSLTLSSLSLSLLSSSSLLLL`. It appears that two problems (among others) are that you're trying to push a 0 onto the stack using `SSSL` instead of `SSSSL`, and also trying to define an "empty" label by using `LSSL` for `skip`.

Comment: Oh, right. I forgot about that. Many whitespace interpreters accept `SL` for zero (including the prebuilt Linux binary, which is the one used on golf.shinh.org). Since it doesn't matter for this problem, I'll use the longer `SSL` form for zero.

Comment: Sorry for the delay ... I just confirmed that indeed Edwin Brady's [Version 0.3 (Linux binary) of the Whitespace interpreter](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/download.php)  does indeed run your program without complaint. I've been using the Ruby implementation (available at the same page), which disallows the syntax you're using.

Answer (score 9):

#### SED (10 distinct bytes, 13 total)

```
s/[aeIou]//gI
```

Sample usage:

```
echo The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dOg. | sed -e s/[aeIou]//gI
```

outputs:

```
Th qck brwn fx jmps vr th lzy dg.
```

Comment: Just wondering, why `I` is uppercase? It works fine when `I` characters are lowercase.

Comment: @GlitchMr I just did that to emphasize that the `I` character is reused.

Comment: Good.  Now, how do you make that work for `Renée’s naïveté`?

Comment: @tchrist I don't think the OP mentioned French vowels in his post. Also, I like writing naïve programs. :-)

Comment: True, but he didn’t rule them out either. English text can contain diacritics, as I’ve shown. Would you like a zoölogist’s perspective on reïnvigorating a snail’s DNA using a splice from a jalapeño?  It makes for the tastiest escargot, especially with a nice Curaçao chaser!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `ö` and `ï` are misused in your example and the other two are consonants. Still, I think you have a point. But this way we may end up supporting ò̟̣̱͉̙t̝͔͖͇͙̦̝h̵̩e͎r͓̥ ̱̼̞̰̠͔k̞̝̮̕i̴̘̟̬̠n̻͜d̦̰̼̰͔s͈̺̝̭ ̫̺͔̠̭̖o̼f̲͘ ͓̮v̳̙͔̝o͔̭̫͕͢ẃ̜͉̪̩̗e̻͔̺̬̣ĺs͖̭̮ as well; perhaps even ,,slǝʍoʌ uʍop ǝpısdn,, :-)

Comment: @w0lf, those uses of `ö` and `ï` were once found in English, though they've nearly disappeared now.

Answer (score 7):

### C, <strike>22</strike> <strike>20</strike> 19 distinct characters.

Letters needed for `main`, `putchar`, `getchar` = 12.
Punctuation - `(){};` = 5.
Operators - `&-`= 2.

```
i;ii;
p(c){
    (c&ii-(-ii-ii))-(i-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii)&&
    (c&ii-(-ii-ii))-(i-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-i-i-i-i)&&
    (c&ii-(-ii-ii))-(i-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-(-i-i-i))&&
    (c&ii-(-ii-ii))-(-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-i-i)&&
    (c&ii-(-ii-ii))-(i-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-(-i-i))&&
    putchar(c);
}
a(c){c-i&&n(p(c));}
n(c){a(getchar());}
main(){
    n(i---ii---ii---ii---ii---ii---ii---ii---ii---ii---ii---ii---i);
}
```

`main` invokes undefined behavior (too much `--` in one line).
I don't care about the expression value, and it does decrement `ii` the right number of times.
Can be fixed easily by separating the decrements with `;`. But it's so much nicer as it is.

Old version, 20 characters:
Actually 21, because I didn't notice that some spaces are significant and must be counted, but they can be replaced with parentheses easily.

```
ii;iii;c;a;
main(i){
    i=c;i-=--c;
    ii=-i-i-i-i-i-i-i-i-i-i-i;
    iii=i-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii;
    -(c=a=getchar())-i&&main(
        (c&=ii- -ii- -ii)- -            a&&
        -ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-  i-         c&&
        -ii-ii-ii-ii-ii-ii- -i- -i- -i- c&&
        iii- -ii- -ii- -ii-  i-i-i-i-i- c&&
        iii- -ii- -ii- -ii- -i-         c&&
        iii- -ii- -ii-       i-i-i-i-   c&&
        putchar(a));
}
```

Can perhaps be improved further, by compiling with `gcc -nostartfiles`, and renaming `main` to `_start`. `min` are removed (after some variable renaming), `_s` added. But then I need to use `exit()`, which adds 3 chars.
Instead of `_start`, any name can be used, and it works in Linux. This allows going down to 18 chars, but is very non-standard.

Answer (score 7):

## Perl: 8 or 10 distinct characters

### `s///` solution: 10 distinct, 13 total

The (purported; see below) sed technique always works in perl, too, and yields the name number of distinct characters (10):

```
s/[aeiou]//gi
```

For example:

```
$ echo 'This program will remove VOWELS. So we can speak without them.' | 
  perl -ple 's/[aeiou]//gi'
Ths prgrm wll rmv VWLS. S w cn spk wtht thm.
```

That’s 10 distinct characters, as this proves:

```
$ echo 's/[aeiou]//gi' | perl -nle '@s{split//}=(); print scalar keys %s'
10
```

The problem with the sed solution is that its `/i` is *not* part of POSIX sed, and thus is not portable:

```
$ echo 'This program will remove VOWELS. So we can speak without them.' | 
  sed -e 's/[aeiou]//gi'
sed: 1: "s/[aeiou]//gi": bad flag in substitute command: 'i'
```

That’s running on an OpenBSD system.  In contrast, because `/i` is indeed always part of standard perl, you ***can*** count on its always being there. Unlike sed.

If you want to include “y” in the list of vowels, it is of course one greater if you use the same technique:

```
$ echo 'This nifty program remove any VOWELS. So we easily can speak without them.' | 
  perl -ple 's/[aeiouy]//gi'
Ths nft prgrm rmv n VWLS. S w sl cn spk wtht thm.

$ echo 's/[aeiouy]//gi' | perl -nle '@s{split//}=(); print scalar keys %s'
11
```

And it is now 14 total characters.

### `tr[][]` solution: 8 distinct 10 total

You could also use `tr///` to remove anything it matches. Perl can even use sed’s `y///` alias for `tr`:

```
y/aeiou//d
```

which is now 8 distinct characters, but does’t work on uppercase.  You end up having to add 5 more characters to cope with the casemaps:

```
$ echo 'y/aeiouAEIOU//d' | perl -nle '@s{split//}=(); print scalar keys %s'
13
```

and of course that’s now 15 total.

However, adding “y” to the mix as a vowel doesn’t up the number of distinct characters as it did with the `s///` version:

```
$ echo 'This nifty program remove any VOWELS. So we easily can speak without them.' | 
  perl -ple 'y/aeiouy//d'
Ths nft prgrm rmv n VOWELS. S w sl cn spk wtht thm.
```

So that’s still just the original 8 distinct out of 11 total:

```
$ echo 'y/aeiouy//d' | perl -nle '@s{split//}=(); print scalar keys %s'
8
```

---

## *EDIT*: Accounting for Diacritics

And what about inputs like `Renée’s naïveté`? The correct output should of course be `Rn’s nvt`.  Here’s how to do that, using v5.14’s `/r` flag for `s///`:

```
$ echo 'Renée’s naïveté' |
  perl5.14.0 -CS -MUnicode::Normalize -nle 'print NFD($_)=~s/[aeiou]\pM*//rgi'
Rn’s nvt
```

That’s 27 distinct characters:

```
$ echo 'print NFD($_) =~ s/[aeiou]\pM*//rgi' | 
  perl -nle '@s{split//}=(); print scalar keys %s'
27
```

You can trim that to 26 if you can guarantee that you’re running at least v5.10 by swapping out the `print` for a `say`:

```
$ echo 'Renée’s naïveté' |
  perl -Mv5.14 -CS -MUnicode::Normalize -nlE 'say NFD($_) =~ s/[aeiou]\pM*//rgi'
Rn’s nvt

$ echo 'say NFD($_) =~ s/[aeiou]\pM*//rgi' | 
  perl -nle '@s{split//}=(); print scalar keys %s'
26
```

And you can get it down to 22 if you don’t mind moving the diacritics instead of removing them:

```
$ echo 'Renée’s naïveté' |
  perl -Mv5.14 -CS -MUnicode::Normalize -nlE 'say NFD($_) =~ s/[aeiou]//rgi'
Rń’s n̈vt́
```

Which is ... *interesting* to look at, to say the least. :)  Here’s its distinct-count:

```
$ echo 'say NFD($_) =~ s/[aeiou]//rgi' | 
  perl -nle '@s{split//}=(); print scalar keys %s'
22
```

### *Good luck getting any other language to properly deal with diacritics using fewer characters than this!*

Comment: ɢᴏᴏᴅ ᴘₒᵢⁿᵗ αβουτ    ,      ℍ?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Most of that’s fixed by committing to an NFKD decomposition. The Greeks don’t count though they’re lookalikes, and the smallcaps don’t decompose to regulars. The result is `"ɢᴏᴏᴅ ᴘnt αβουτ dcrtcs y gt thr, bvt hw bt stff lk THS"`, or `"\N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL G}\N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL O}\N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL O}\N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL D} \N{LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL P}nt \N{GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA}\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA}\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON}\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER UPSILON}\N{GREEK SMALL LETTER TAU} dcrtcs y gt thr, bvt hw bt stff lk THS"`.

Comment: But are there are some Latin vowels that don't have compatibility decompositions, such as `ø`.

Comment: @dan04 True, although `ø` (and `ǿ`) both have a primary collation strength that is equal to that of `o` in the DUCET used by the Unicode Collation Algorithm. Similarly with the insular letters, the combining letters, the small caps, etc: in all cases, the UCA1 strength would work better than either NFD or even NFKD. We don’t get that till Level 3 in tr18, although I’d like to get it at Level 2 somehow. And of course, if it were Welsh, they’d need `w` to be a vowel. Many languages that use the Latin script have “interestinger” notions of vowels than we may be used to.

Comment: challenge doesn't say to remove vowels with diacritics -- just a,e,i,o,u -- so `Renée’s naïveté` should give `Rné’s nïvté`.

Comment: Why would greek vowels not count, if äèïóű etc. (not in [a,e,i,o,u]!) do? Or Cyrillic, for that matter (which aren't lookalikes, but sure enough vowels).

Answer (score 6):

### GolfScript (7 distinct bytes, 103 total)

Sufficiently much of an improvement over [w0lf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3527/w0lf)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6038/194) that I think it qualifies as a separate one:

```
[9-99))--9+99))99))))))99)9+))9-9)99--)99-9+9--9+9-))99-9+9)))--9+99-9+-9+9-)99-9+9)))-)99)9-9-)))]''+-
```

#### 12 distinct bytes, 13 total:

```
'aeiouAEIOU'-
```

Comment: Great! I wish I could upvote you again.

Answer (score 4):

#### Golfscript (8 distinct bytes, 837 total)

```
[9)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 9)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 9)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 9)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 9)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 9)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 9)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 9)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 9)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))) 9))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))]''+-
```

Explanation:

1. The program creates the following array of integer values: `[97 101 105 111 117 65 69 73 79 85]` (corresponding to the ASCII codes of `a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U`). Each number is represented by pushing on stack the value `9`, followed by the needed number of `)` (increment operators). For example, the number `67` is obtained using `9` and 58 `)`s
2. Using `''+`, the array is converted into the string `"a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U"`, representing all vowels
3. The subtraction sign ('-') is then used to subtract all vowels from the source string

The 8 unique characters that were used: `[`,`]`,`9`,`)`,`+`,`-`,`'` and `(space)`

Answer (score 4):

### Unreadable (2 distinct, 2666 total)

Since everyone is posting Turing tarpits, I thought I'd use this one. It's not a very well-known one but it does exist ( http://esolangs.org/wiki/Unreadable ) and it has only two characters.

```
'""""'""""'""""'""""""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"""""'"""""""'"""'""""'"""
"'""""'""""""'"""'""""""""'"""""""'"""'""""""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'"""'"""
"'""""""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""
'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"
"'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""""
"""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""
'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""
'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""""
"""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'
""'""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""""'""""
""""'""""""""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""'"
"'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""""'""""""""'"""
""""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""""'""""""""'""""""""'"""""""
"'"""""""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""""""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""'""""""'""
'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""""""'""'"""'"
"""'""""""'"""'""'""""""""""'"""""'"""""""'"""'""""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"
"'""'""'"""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'
"""'""""""""'"""'""""'"""""""""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""
""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'
""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""""""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'
"""'"""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""'"""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'
""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""
'""'"""'""""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'
""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""
'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""'""""'"""""""""'"""""""'"
"'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'
""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""'""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'
""'""'"""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"""'""""'"""""""""'""""""
""'""""""""'""""""""'""""""""'""""""""'""""""""'""""""""'""""""""'""""""""'"""""""'""'""'
""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'""'"""'"'""""""""'"""""""'"""'"""'""""""'"""'""'""""""""""
```

Comment: (+1) Nice ... I verified it with [your interpreter](http://esolangs.org/wiki/User:Marinus/Unreadable_Interpreter). Is it still considered "unapproved", even though the creator of this language [approved it](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Talk:Unreadable)?  (It  seems a shame that the language wasn't defined using two whitespace characters instead of single- and double-quotes ;o)))

Comment: @r.e.s. That shouldn't be hard to implement. Just pick two [whitespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)#Spaces_in_Unicode) and modify the interpreter so that it replaces the whitespaces by the single- and double-quotes at first!

Answer (score 2):

### VBA - <strike>25</strike> 22 distinct bytes (120 total)

I know this won't win with so many different bytes, but here it is in VBA.

`(space)`,`(newline)`,`"`,`,`,`(`,`)`,`=`,`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`E`,`I`,`l`,`n`,`O`,`p`,`R`,`S`,`u`,`1`

```vb
Sub S(u)
u=Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(u,"u","",,,1),"O","",,,1),"I","",,,1),"e","",,,1),"a","",,,1)
End Sub
```

*<sub>`,,,1` allows for ignoring case. (`1` represents the constant `vbTextCompare`)</sub>

Comment: You didn't count the `E` in `End Sub`. But quite nice, considering it's Basic.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks! Absolutely right about `E`, and I've corrected. I think I was too worried about the meat of the Sub. ;-)

Comment: Actually, as VBA as a language suppotts autoformatting, you can change your answer to be in all lower (or upper) case and VBA will correct for this itself, and because it is accepted that autoformatting languages may be considered before the autoformatting occurs, that would mean that you can drop either the `e` or `E`

Comment: you could configure this down to an immediate window function as `?Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(cells(1,1),"u","",,,1),"O","",,,1),"I","",,,1),"e","",,,1),"a","",,,1)` with by my count 18 Distinct Bytes `?Replace(s1,)"uOI` and 111 bytes total

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 6 (7325 total)

```js
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]])+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]])()((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]+(![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+(![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[+[]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[[]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]([[]])+[]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+([+[]]+![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])
```

This uses [JSFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) to turn `r=>r.replace(/[aeiou]/g,"")` into six unique characters.

Comment: You would need to add the `i` flag as well to satisfy the challenge requirements.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 25 total bytes, 15 distinct bytes

```scala
_ filterNot "aeiou".toSet
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tOczovYFRxmzClRcmGcalA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Itr](https://github.com/bsoelch/OneChar.js/blob/main/ItrLang.md), 4 distinct characters, 5197 bytes

*newlines for readability*

```
(
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
(()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()())L
)©
```

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=Itr&src=KCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkpTCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSlMKCgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkpTCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkpTCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSlMKCgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkpTCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkpTCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwoKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkpTCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkpTCgoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKCkoKSgpKUwpqQ==&in=IlRoaXMgcHJvZ3JhbSB3aWxsIHJlbW92ZSBWT1dFTFMuClNvIHdlIGNhbiBub3cgc3BlYWsgd2l0aG91dCB0aGVtLiI=)

### Explanation

It is possible to execute arbitrary Itr code using only `()L©`: 
`(()...())` creates an array of empty arrays 
`L` gets the length of that array 
`©` interprets the (flattened) array as a sequence of characters and executes that sequence

The code that is encoded by this program is `äµ»»AEIOUaeiou«=S¬«×`:

```
ä                     ; duplicate the (implicit) input
 µ»               «   ; map over all characters in the input
   »AEIOUaeiou«=S     ; is the character in the string "AEIOUaeiou"
                 ¬    ; negated
                    × ; pick the elements that have a one in the second array
```

Answer (score 1):

## K, 29. (18 distinct bytes)

```
{i@&~(i:0:0)in(_i),i:"AEIOU"}
```

distinct bytes: {@&~(:0)in_,"AEIOU}

```
k){i@&~(i:0:0)in(_i),i:"AEIOU"}`
Hello WoOOrld
"Hll Wrld"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3.x, 19 distinct chars, 62 total

```
print(''.join(x for x in input() if x.lower() not in 'aeiou'))
```

Comment: That doesn’t work properly on inputs like `Renée’s naïveté`, you know.

Answer (score 1):

### J, 21 characters (18 distinct)

```
'AEIOUaeiou'-.~1!:1[1
```

Answer (score 1):

**ASM - 6 distinct characters 520 source characters**
(MsDOS .com)

Assembled using A86

```
db 10110100xb
db 00000110xb
db 10110010xb
db 11111111xb
db 11001101xb
db 00100001xb
db 01110101xb
db 00000001xb
db 11000011xb
db 10001010xb
db 11010000xb
db 10111110xb
db 00011101xb
db 00000001xb
db 10111001xb
db 00001010xb
db 00000000xb
db 01000110xb
db 00101010xb
db 00000100xb
db 01110100xb
db 11101010xb
db 11100010xb
db 11111001xb
db 10110100xb
db 00000110xb
db 11001101xb
db 00100001xb
db 11101011xb
db 11100010xb
db 01000001xb
db 00000100xb
db 00000100xb
db 00000110xb
db 00000110xb
db 00001100xb
db 00000100xb
db 00000100xb
db 00000110xb
db 00000110xb
```

Comment: Just write the machine language, it will be two distinct characters.

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 8 bytes (all distinct)

```
t13Y2m~)
```

[Try it on MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=t13Y2m%7E%29&inputs=%5B%27This+program+will+remove+VOWELS.%27+10+%27So+we+can+now+speak+without+them.%27%5D&version=20.9.2)

Just a straight up golf, didn't really find any trick to reuse characters to reduce unique bytecount.

`13Y2` is a literal containing `aeiouAEIOU`.

Take a duplica`t`e of the input string, make a logical (boolean) array indicating which letters of the input are not (`~`) `m`embers of that literal, and index (`)`) at those places, to return an array of only non-vowel characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 16 bytes, 14 distinct

**Solution:**

```
^[;v,_v:"AEIOU"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/Py7aukwnvsxKydHV0z9UKVYpJCOzWKGgKD@9KDFXoTwzJ0ehKDU3vyxVIcw/3NUnWOn/fwA)

**Explanation:**

Using except (`^`) to filter out the vowels.

```
^[;v,_v:"AEIOU"] / the solution
^[;            ] / except (^) projection
      v:"AEIOU"  / save vowels as v
     _           / lowercase (_), "AEIOU" => "aeiou"
    ,            / join (,)
   v             / uppercase vowels
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes, 4 distinct characters

```
k∨$F
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=k%E2%88%A8%24F&inputs=This%20program%20will%20remove%20VOWELS.%0ASo%20we%20can%20now%20speak%20without%20them.&header=&footer=)

Only works with single-line strings. Explanation:

```
      # Implicit input
k∨    # Constant "aeiouAEIOU"
  $   # Swap top two values
   F  # Remove from second string any characters in first string
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Unary, ~3.081e<sup>1915</sup> bytes, 1 distinct character

Specifically, [this](https://tio.run/##HZVHlhtJDESvBCBhjyOtZj/3f9SPUktsUlkJE45///z/3@/3bD1qMtcn5vnUWURdXfY@776XrznvvLOOmHnVs/bOo3mMd5M31f48wi85uJ2J63zLwTObmtu8vDCaUSfMeq6eHq/YRw@rNb/m5NzMffnok@71us3Kh1pB9bW59@qte4/vo3CzBY2YuIx/@2ap7ZGUnXjba8yyUY/We2@acavt0W4CALKDWh1jZekZkXMsXsvYM9fHoq9fr1t9e8XktmVbF5MNk9MWZGwplTv8bDnAWdMjfBs0GScH7IBmOlj6bCO2kvtU5j0fLllzuHvTm8DNZIKHY0EERS@y0tqzWXm3wwsmfNztEjCBrPri9ri9uckFE5Wgmc2kx1T3QK6LuYa6QDvCADaWQ2@wZUHoSoBkF@iuiO4cgXOqrM24EeJi@Ln1E4aQXGBw/kYNgWT0clDzgELsTkl0miEOfk56WW5BabJbgKK0dgDykt0MPsGMUQBQfWi3DWKcqLVJfiBXLJ1RxgmyQKv82keR5S8Ft3nGTuqTvr8dwZsJ7YmEhAaaanQ/PvFBB@jK6ZSGzhEgACModDwyhjG9MwF2OP5MY5/HgvbeNYXn27pY62EQJPOGWsEmQAJ6iJn3JZ1D24tG0oYTgRWs8zEdzeGaBZAF7oBhTFMswoWskVoW5pEUPKJgtCLNMv5rsfoY7/UhPAyLaq0ScQf@oxIgJBeA2JdS3oXkgLuQ36k6CADjFSfOffFZsAErQN4rTUSLATmI7WHiBTyaCnSKbWkHUoq3sDD9yYunV7YHBwMz@oCD25MlGT9O0wECUGBg1jbNSFOISwxN5eb5EaIpfnm49JvthkZwii@gHuRJnnKswVJMiUTkEBZ4UnDBfMlK@AIEjZQohR1yHqyFMHgCp@MCrQNumxwmmMZj0YR5RII8ekGOBAEyQglpc/265CviQTCGy85PYVA03S8FiBpYEcLE3mgMpxuyihUW2sSXjPrUYqFJ0fLRkK6QQPAYDR6ZS5SZoom9yUQ4wuPATFHxGSXTY7RTasmCMhZAsxeDQzCxSs5BuuKGKGY4npA1cTvTucIOsRPe@RmJQKervMxbGc957IUk98FLH8NMuAgzDQPTDWvqq8DIMaZE7dpw9F@8SrFGRzR2kjBxfXIk@h6FMk02v28R8kH4wccXYcvzKBqTo6@USnGjLVhR3Vyx5uQbsUDGkb/enwWhMJSmXquvQQKQnivpEB/oFoSRM@C6WGR/RAmeC/FkL2lAUiFtVnIjgNBF8IWFMeEA/khPrHeUQBCURGeswUvs/H7/AA) is how many `0`s are required. Simply a Unary port of the [brainfuck answer by @ceased to turn clockwis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6033/101522).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ḟØc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmHZyT///8/JCOzWKGgKD@9KDFXoTwzJ0ehKDU3vyxVIcw/3NUnWI8rOF@hPFUhOTFPIS@/XKG4IDUxG6iuJCO/tEShJCM1Vw8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 17 bytes, 13 distinct

```apl
((⌊,⊢)'AEIOU')~⍨⊢
 (⌊,⊢)'AEIOU' ⍝ concatenate with lower case version of string
   ~⍨⊢ ⍝ remove vowels
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R2wQNjUc9XTqPuhZpqju6evqHqmvWPepdAeQDpRXU3fLznRKL1AE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 7 distinct bytes, <s>2091</s> 2082 bytes

```python
c="%c%%c%%%%c%%%%%%%%c"
ex=c==c
ee=c==""
exec"e=%x%%x"%ex%ex
exec"e%%%%%%%%=%x%%x%%%%x"%ee%ex%ee
exec"ee=%x%%x"%e%ee
exec"ee%%%%=%x%%x"%ex%e
exec"e=%x%%x"%ee%e
exec"ec=ex%cex"%e
exec"xe=ec%cec"%e
exec"xx=xe%cxe"%e
exec"xc=xx%cxx"%e
exec"ce=xc%cxc"%e
exec"cc=ce%cce"%e
exec"xee=ce%cec"%e
exec"cee=ce%cxx"%e
exec"exe=ce%cex%%cxx"%e%e
exec"xxe=ce%cec%%cxe%%%%cxx"%e%e%e
exec"cxe=ce%cec%%cxx%%%%cxc"%e%e%e
exec"ece=cc%cex"%e
exec"xce=cc%cex%%cxe"%e%e
exec"cce=cc%cex%%cxx"%e%e
exec"eex=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cxe%%%%%%%%cxx"%e%e%e%e
exec"xex=cc%cex%%cxe%%%%cxc"%e%e%e
exec"cex=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%cxc"%e%e%e%e
exec"exx=cc%cex%%cxe%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%cxc"%e%e%e%e
exec"xxx=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cxe%%%%%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%cxc"%e%e%e%e%e
exec"cxx=cc%cex%%cce"%e%e
exec"ecx=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"xcx=cc%cex%%cxe%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"ccx=cc%cec%%cxe%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"eec=cc%cxx%%cce"%e%e
exec"xec=cc%cex%%cxx%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"cec=cc%cec%%cxx%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"exc=cc%cxe%%cxx%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"xxc=cc%cec%%cxe%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e
exec"cxc=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cxe%%%%%%%%cxx%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e%e
exec"ecc=cc%cxc%%cce"%e%e
exec"xcc=cc%cec%%cxc%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"ccc=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cxc%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e
exec"eeee=cc%cxe%%cxc%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"xeee=cc%cex%%cxe%%%%cxc%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e
exec"ceee=cc%cec%%cxe%%%%cxc%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e
exec"exee=cc%cex%%cec%%%%cxe%%%%%%%%cxc%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%cce"%e%e%e%e%e
exec"xxee=cc%cxx%%cxc%%%%cce"%e%e%e
exec"""x=""
"""
exec"x%c=c%%xcx%%xxee%%xcx%%ecx"%e
exec"x%c=c%%xee%%xee%%xxe%%cec"%e
exec"x%c=c%%cxc%%xec%%xxc%%cee"%e
exec"x%c=c%%ecx%%eec%%xcc%%cee"%e
exec"x%c=c%%xcx%%ceee%%cxx%%exc"%e
exec"x%c=c%%cee%%ecx%%exe%%exe"%e
exec"x%c=c%%ccx%%cxc%%xcc%%ce"%e
exec"x%c=c%%ecx%%ce%%xec%%xxc"%e
exec"x%c=c%%ce%%ecx%%xxee%%xxe"%e
exec"x%c=c%%ccc%%ecc%%exc%%xec"%e
exec"x%c=c%%eeee%%cee%%exe%%exe"%e
cx="""ecc
xcc
xec
xxc
eeee
xee
xee
xxe
cec
cxc
xec
xxc
cee
cxx
cex
cxx
ce
xec
xxc
xee
cxx
xcx
xec
cxc
xeee
ece
xce
cce
eex
xex
xee
cxe
exx
ccx
cxc
xcc
ce
cxx
ce
xec
xxc
ce
xcc
cxx
exee
xxx
xec
xxc
ecc
xeee
eeee
cee
exe
exe"""
exec"exec%cx"%ce
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVXLjtswDLznK1wD/oHedehhge4pp35AMR00wQZJkATN7NenpB6W/Mh2G9iyQw6HQ4qQz@@33en49fFA6AcMfuUlvvQbKiAEbEh/9m4geoZBw6B@oOzKthKVfP7mAEYMM6YGNrYalAjnOTiaEMwPujFZxECYBdWiIA4QqwVBFqUaBQZZlGoUEGBRaKK8Yk6okU0Nky0JZVKTveoo8e6JNRbAyDeBKEEwgdCkAtOSR9OQy6xFtJ5WDH0bi4dpkzVuWNVVi1ebY00Z1ihVKTGjpFYoP8BL/5A8zH4tRe1wQ4K2V8SSPgNqo5eKZxAUCJ5CaEPrEC0kKHvydq3yFwieQqjMz6cQCQuVTetHdO0a/rP1DUVtcNaFRd1o5WC9rysK8FwxSTZdWN/OgpkO9QdtGAPwuQCqzbDSOHymcSoscWLWa@l7@Vncl/PYjrdgQJtYW@Qnany1Ia/HRoZEZ1xir9qTMyFiSrl6xb0j5whG7ojAOiJm9/7lcaGWadyZmFwItSABSgNymlUdYFW7zJFBKhUvc0QeRImRaJEkVUFOhcI3wId8I79pt/wraV81lVsGM4eVMAKMx/7LnsrP0aXsst5FWwrzr6SD7LYhsATuVAa7UuOAEhjOP6eNwYhWJlWqclFS@IL0RfZ7HCxfBp8i8PH4zsPh1N12@2tn18/uervsj7@7@/626/6c3nm4dl@6b8dfBnm9dvft5a27v5rvx/n8culu2@1f)

I'm using the algorithm of [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110722/103772) to translate the following code in the code above to only use `e`, `x`, `c`, `"`, `=`, `%` and newline. Make sure to follow the link to understand how the transformation works

### code before transformation: (<s>57</s> 54 bytes)

```python
print"".join(a[a in"aeiouAEIOU":]for a in raw_input())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCsIwFEV/5ZqpXRwc3ToUzJSpk4gErOZpeC8kr4Z@fYxwp3MON@0ahE@tpUysxhzfQjz4qwex8SvJNs3WLeZ8e0rGnyL7eidOmw7j2NpljVGggQr6PIr2oxcqacBX9jUWHDDxoye2oLr8QbXdLSnNGercDw)

Even if the first code isn't golfed, this one is :p

Thanks to dingledooper for -3 bytes on the second program

Comment: By the way, I think you can do `a[a in"aeiouAEIOU":]` which is 3 bytes shorter.

Comment: @dingledooper I didn' thought of that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 12 distinct characters, <strike>3245</strike> 2924 bytes

```lua
load(('').char(#'################################################################################################################')..'r'..('').char(#'#########################################################################################################')..('').char(#'##############################################################################################################')..('').char(#'####################################################################################################################')..'(('..('').char(#'#########################################################################################################')..'o'..('').char(#'##############################################')..'r'..('').char(#'#####################################################################################################')..'ad'..('').char(#'#######################################')..('').char(#'##########################################')..'a'..('').char(#'#######################################')..('').char(#'##########################################################')..('').char(#'#######################################################################################################')..('').char(#'###################################################################################################################')..('').char(#'#####################################################################################################################')..('').char(#'##################################################################################################')..'('..('').char(#'#######################################')..('').char(#'###########################################################################################')..'a'..('').char(#'#####################################################################################################')..('').char(#'#########################################################################################################')..'o'..('').char(#'#####################################################################################################################')..('').char(#'#################################################################')..('').char(#'#####################################################################')..('').char(#'#########################################################################')..('').char(#'###############################################################################')..('').char(#'#####################################################################################')..('').char(#'#############################################################################################')..('').char(#'#######################################')..('').char(#'############################################')..('').char(#'#######################################')..('').char(#'#######################################')..')))')()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1ZS/DoIwEId3n@ISh2uXvoWbiQNG5wYaSywcKSCPXxEWZ7C92rnJd3@@37lRh@BIV0IgSlVa7cURj4nfTFboUSmWIj50vu556V/znw1gXADSLjqfQQtZV9vQ25e/YlNTM5E3g8zkEFuGItZLwa1d1HT8qRc/OKK5jiDKTKMtKrIBSQRLavFG2J4a0yKXaEopUQoZwtXWPXSeHl43MNXOgTcNvQzcLvfTuVCHgmAyUOoWWpqg74x@zv8GS@MAgzWNegM)

Uses the characters `#load(').chr`. Essentially, this program builds the string `print((io.read'*a':gsub('[aeiouAEIOU]','')))`, loads it as a function, and then runs it.

Thanks to [xigoi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98955/xigoi) for saving about 300 bytes.

Comment: You can decrease the length by using literals for `(` and `)`, as you're already doing for some other characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 8 distinct, 557 bytes

```ruby
eval""<<11+11+11+1+1+1<<11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1<<"<<"<<11+11+11+1+1+1<<"<"<<11+11+11+11+1+1<<111+1+1+1<<"ea"<<11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1<<11+11+11+11+1+1<<11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1<<111+1+1+1+1<<111+1+1+1+1+1+1<<11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1<<11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1<<11+11+11+11+1+1+1<<11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1<<"ae"<<11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1<<111<<111+1+1+1+1+1+1<<11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1<<11+11+11+11+1+1+1<<11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1<<11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1<<111+11+1<<111+11+1+1+1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWt5h0U8sSc5SUbGwMDbWhCASR-QhRbbisEhih61FCFYSbhFCQmoiuAg1h1Y9buTa6HWgcAiZgQnRP4TCECHOBvk1MJeBbVPPJcjppDiPKr_AwRGGBICTVQBPPgptOIRmZxQoFRfnpRYm5CuWZOTkKRam5-WWpCmH-4a4-wXpcwfkK5akKyYl5Cnn55QrFBamJ2UB1JRn5pSUKJRmpuXoQowA)

Encodes the following 30 byte (21 unique) program in the minimum distinct characters `eval"<1+` using the technique from [GB's answer to this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110764/52194).

```ruby
$><<$<.read.gsub(/[aeiou]/i){}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 17 distinct, 28 bytes

```
a:
{a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U}=>*
```

If we didn't have to support uppercase letters, **12 distinct, 18 bytes**:

```
a:
{a,e,i,o,u}=>*
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 2.25 bytes, 2 distinct characters

```
011110011111001000
```

[Try it Online! (link is to bitstring)](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIhIiwiIiwiMDExMTEwMDExMTExMDAxMDAwIiwiIiwid2FpdCJd)

Vyncode FTW! The actual program is encoded as a bitstring. I also shaved a character off of @Aaroneous Miller's answer

Answer (score 0):

### PHP - 30 distinct bytes

```
<?=preg_replace('/[aeiou]/i','',fgets(STDIN));
```

Comment: Couldn't you change `/[aeiou|AEIOU]/` into `/[aeiou]/i`? Also, your code also causes `|` to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

#### bash 26 distinct, 37 total

```
c=$(cat -)
echo "${c//[aeiouAEIOU]/}"
```

sorted:

```
""$$()-///=AEIOU[]aacccceehiootu{}"

scala> code.toList.distinct.length
res51: Int = 26

scala> code.length
res52: Int = 37

"
  ""$$()-///=AEIOU[]aacccceehiootu{}"

    
scala> code.distinct.sorted 
res56: String = 
"
 "$()-/=AEIOU[]acehiotu{}"
```

Result (preserves linefeeds):

```
echo "This program will remove VOWELS.
So we can now speak without them." | ./cg-6025-remove-vowels.sh
Ths prgrm wll rmv VWLS.
S w cn nw spk wtht thm.
```

For tr, it isn't clear how to count: '-d aeiouAEIOU' as 10 or 13:

```
echo "This program will remove VOWELS.
So we can now speak without them." | tr -d aeiouAEIOU
```

Comment: I considered using tr, but I concluded that since it's not a programming language it would have to be wrapped in a shell, so it would count the full text of `tr -d aeiouAEIOU` for 15.

Comment: 16 <!-- char-threshold-gymnastics -->

Comment: 15 distinct, 16 total.

Answer (score 0):

### F# <strike>105 121</strike> 91 characters

```
Console.ReadLine()|>Seq.filter(fun c->not("aeiouAEIOU".Contains(c)))|>Seq.iter(printf"%c")
```

Comment: Hmmm... I just noticed that this code will work in Linqpad but not in Visual Studio. And since I don't feel like down voting my own contribution, I will leave it here with this comment until I figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

### Excel Formula - 19 distinct bytes (196 total)

`=`,`S`,`B`,`T`,`(`,`)`,`,`,`"`,`a`,`e`,`i`,`o`,`u`,`A`,`E`,`I`,`O`,`U`,`1`

```
Cell A1: <Value>
Cell B1: =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a",""),"e","")
Cell C1: =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"i",""),"o",""),"u",""),"A",""),"E",""),"I",""),"O",""),"U","")
```

<strike>*This actually is too many nested functions to work in Excel 2003, but the concept is there.</strike>

**Splitting the formulas into two cells achieved the desired effect.** -- Result is in C1.

Answer (score 0):

## Noether, 16 individual bytes (17 total)

```
I"[aeiouAEIOU]"-P
```

[**Try it online!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=SSJbYWVpb3VBRUlPVV0iLVA&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi)

Uses the regex

```
[aeiouAEIOU]
```

to remove the vowels from the input string.

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 119 bytes, 15 distinct characters

```
explode-[121-2-2,111,111-2-2-2,111-2-2-2-2-2,111-12-2,111-22-2-2,111-21-11,111-22-12-2-2,111-21-21,111-22-22-2]|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@1oiAnPyVVN9rQyFDXSNdIx9DQEIRBbAgPwoLzDOHCSCqAwoYwQUMUcSO4OAjF1mTmgu37/18pJCOzWKGgKD@9KDFXoTwzJ0ehKDU3vyxVIcw/3NUnWE/pX35BSWZ@XvF/3SIA)

Here's how is works.

```
explode
```

Converts the input, which has to be a quoted string or `jq` can't parse it, to an array of codepoints.

```
-[121-2-2,111,111-2-2-2,111-2-2-2-2-2,111-12-2,111-22-2-2,111-21-11,111-22-12-2-2,111-21-21,111-22-22-2]
```

Remove all occurrences of upper and lower case vowels, which are representing as numeric expressions that map to the codepoints.  You COULD make a program with one less unique character by limiting the expressions to `1` and `-`, but it would be very long...

```
|implode
```

Converts the array of codepoints left into a string and prints it.

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 26 bytes

```
|%{$_-replace'[aeiou]',''}
```

Anything before the `|` will be devowel'd.

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 11 distinct characters, 263 bytes

```
<,_v#-''-''-'':_v#----'<'~':_v#--'-<':_v#--#'''-:'-'':_v#-:'-'':_v#---''-'-#'~':_v#--''v':_v#---,'-'-,'v':_v#--,'-'--:'~':_v#--,'-'-@':~@#
v<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@30YkvU9ZVV4cgKxAHCNRt1OugHHVdGyhLWR2oxgquzApJA0gzUB6uR70MJqMDktGB88FcoNY6ZL6DulWdgzJXmc3Agf//HV09/UMB)

Basically, checks each character against each of `AEIOUaeiou`, whose code points are constructed from the code points of the characters used elsewhere in the program, `#',-:<@_v~`.

The program also contains a newline. I'm pretty sure with much editing this could get down to 10 or even 9 characters by replacing `v` and the newline with some other method of returning to the start without the extra line, and there may be a way to also remove `<` in that case by leveraging a `_`.

For example:

The first chunk of code after the character read (right to left above, presented here left to right for clarity) is `:'@-'-',--#v_`. `:` duplicates the character, `'@-` subtracts the value `@` (64) from the character, `'-',-` subtracts `,` (44) from `-` (45) to get 1, which is then subtracted (`-`) from the character, in total subtracting by 65, the code point for `A`. Then `#v_` checks if this total is 0 (the character is A), and either sends the program down and to the next input or continues through the other vowels. If it passes all the checks, the character is printed.

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 35 distinct characters

This complete `program` requires a processor supporting features of Extended Pascal (as defined by ISO standard 10206), in particular the `index` function needs to be present.
Note, to avoid the drama associated with all sorts of various end‑of‑line markers, Pascal (as defined by the ISO standard 7185 and 10206) says that for a `text` file (such as `input`) substitutes the end‑of‑line marker (whatever it may be) with a single space character (`' '`).
Therefore the `program` does not reproduce the example’s *two* lines but *one* line joined by a space.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var c:char;begin while not eof do begin read(c);if 0=index('AEIOUaeiou',c)then write(c)end end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program removeVowelsWithoutUsingTooManyDifferentCharacters(input, output);
    var
        currentCharacter: char;
    begin
        while not EOF(input) do
        begin
            { This is equivalent to `currentCharacter ≔ input↑; get(input);`. }
            read(input, currentCharacter);
            
            { `index` returns zero if the pattern `currentCharacter`
              does not appear in the sample `'AEIOUaeiou'`. }
            if index('AEIOUaeiou', currentCharacter) = 0 then
            begin
                { Equivalent to `output↑ ≔ currentCharacter; put(output);`. }
                write(output, currentCharacter);
            end;
        end;
    end.
```

Answer (score -1):

## Python (23)

Somebody had to do it.

```
print filter(lambda x:x not in'aeiou',raw_input())
```

Comment: That has "only" 23 distinct characters. But fails to work on uppercase vowels.

Comment: By adding one new character and changing the variable from x to either c or s you can use lowercase() (or uppercase) and deal also with uppercase vowels.