# Replace twos with threes

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, number-theory

Given a positive integer n write some code to take its prime factorization and replace all of its factors of `2` with `3`.

For example

```
12 = 2 * 2 * 3 -> 3 * 3 * 3 = 27
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the byte count of your answer.

## Test cases

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 3
3 -> 3
4 -> 9
5 -> 5
6 -> 9
7 -> 7
8 -> 27
9 -> 9
10 -> 15
11 -> 11
12 -> 27
13 -> 13
14 -> 21
15 -> 15
16 -> 81
17 -> 17
18 -> 27
19 -> 19
20 -> 45
21 -> 21
22 -> 33
23 -> 23
24 -> 81
25 -> 25
26 -> 39
27 -> 27
28 -> 63
29 -> 29
```

Answer (score 71):

## [Fractran](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fractran), 3 bytes

```
3/2
```

Fractran literally only has one builtin, but it happens to do exactly what this task is asking for. (It's also Turing-complete, by itself.)

The language doesn't really have a standardised syntax or interpreter. [This interpreter](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2006/10/28/more-fractran-a-trivial-interp-1/#comment-3759) (in a comment to a blog post –
 it's a very simple language) will accept the syntax shown here. (There are other Fractran interpreters with other syntaxes, e.g. some would write this program as `3 2`, or even using `3` and `2` as command line arguments, which would lead to a score of 0+3 bytes. I doubt it's possible to do better than 3 in a pre-existing interpreter, though.)

### Explanation

```
3/2
 /   Replace a factor of
  2  2
3    with 3
     {implicit: repeat until no more replacements are possible}
```

Comment: Talk about right tool for the job..

Comment: _"Don't upvote trivial solutions that only uses a simple builtin."_ Well, in this case: _Knowing that there's a language "Fractran" that has a single builtin that solves this specific task is by itself impressive._

Comment: Does this do primer factorization?

Comment: @Pandya: Some Fractran implementations use prime factorization internally (as an optimization), but they don't have to; the language operates on factors, not prime factors. (It just happens that 2 and 3 are prime.)

Comment: Related SO code golf (pre-PPCG): [Write a Fractran interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749905/code-golf-fractran).

Comment: Why does this exist? Its confusing. What was Conway looking for/studying?

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Likely looking for a Turing-complete language that's very simple/easy to implement. Fractran is really elegant as Turing tarpits go; most have a lot more rough edges, special cases, or details that could be changed without making a large difference.

Comment: @AnderBiguri It looks like it came out of his studies of the Collatz conjecture; he proved that a generalization of Collatz is equivalent to Fractran and that Fractran is Turing-complete, therefore generalized Collatz is undecidable.

Answer (score 24):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n%2*n or 3*f(n/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJBnladqpJWnkF@kYKyVppGnb6T5Pw3IyVPIzFMoSsxLT9Uw1DE20LTi4iwoyswrUQCq0fwPAA)

Recursively divide the number by 2 and multiplies the result by 3, as long as the number is even. Odd numbers return themselves.

**32 byte alt:**

```python
lambda n:n*(n&-n)**0.58496250072
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZ5WnpZGnppunqaVloGdqYWJpZmRqYGBu9D8tv0ghTyEzT6EoMS89VcNQx9hA04qLs6AoM69EIU0jT/M/AA). Has some float error. The constant is `log_2(3)-1`.

Uses `(n&-n)` to find the greatest power-of-2 factor of `n`, the converts `3**k` to `2**k` by raising it to the power of `log_2(3)-1`.

Comment: Nice this is my solution exactly!

Comment: @WheatWizard Me as well, aha!

Answer (score 19):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
Ò1~P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#M7L0Kav8f3iSYV3A/0qlw/utFA7vV9L5DwA)

#### How it works

```
Ò     Compute the prime factorization of the input.
 1~   Perform bitwise OR with 1, making the only even prime (2) odd (3).
   P  Take the product of the result.
```

Comment: This beats Jelly by 1 byte simply because prime factorization is only one byte here :(

Comment: @HyperNeutrino: I noticed that too: "why is Dennis using 05AB1E? Oh, identical algorithm, shorter builtin names". So I had to go and find a language where I could do it in even fewer bytes, via the use of an even more appropriate set of builtins.

Answer (score 14):

### Haskell, <s>24</s> 23 bytes

```
until odd$(*3).(`div`2)
```

The divide by two and multiply by 3 until odd trick in Haskell.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgopCbWKCgoVCaV5KZo5CfkqKioWWsqaeRkJJZlmCkqaCpEG2op2dkGfv/PwA)

Alternative with a lambda instead of a pointfree function and with the same byte count:

```
odd`until`\x->div(x*3)2
```

Edit: @ais523 saved a byte in the original version and @Ørjan Johansen one in the alternative version, so both version have still the same length. Thanks!

Comment: The lambda version can be shortened to ``odd`until`\x->div(x*3)2``.

Comment: The original version can also be shortened one byte via using `$` to replace a pair of parentheses: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgopCbWKCgoVCaV5KZo5CfkqKioWWsqaeRkJJZlmCkqaCpEG2op2dkGfv/PwA "Haskell – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: ah, nice! Thanks.

Comment: @ais523: How could I have missed that one, Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot to remove a pair of `()` from the lambda version

Comment: @CAD97: Yes, I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript (ES6), 19 bytes

```
f=x=>x%2?x:f(x*1.5)
```

While the input is divisible by two, multiplies it by 1.5, which is equivalent to dividing by 2 and multiplying by 3.

Comment: `x*3/2` has the same bytecount

Comment: `f=` is usally not needed for js.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks, but in order to call itself `f(x*1.5)` it needs to have the name `f`, hence why the `f=` is included.

Comment: @ETHproductions Uhm ... of course ! I missed that. Is there any meta on what the calling code exactly looks like?

Comment: @Christoph [Here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10361/42545) is the relevant meta post.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-babel-node#@59mW2FrV6FqZF9hlaZRoWWoZ6r5Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI03DyEJT8z8A)

Answer (score 8):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 76 bytes

```
{{({}[()]<([({})]()<({}{})>)>)}{}([{}]()){{}((({})){}{})<>}<>}<>({}({}){}())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#HYrBDQAwCALXgX@fxkVMJyHObrHRyOVkJKgLvIEy8YLhNKXHiVJbUkZsg/8b2X9tVvqSM@cB)

### Explanation

This program works by dividing the number by two and tripling until it gets a remainder of one from the division. Then it stops looping and doubles and adds one to the final number.

#### More detailed explanation eventually...

Comment: > Coming soon ...

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>22</s> 19 bytes

*Thanks to lanlock4 for saving 3 bytes!*

```
#//.x_?EvenQ:>3x/2&
```

Pure function that does the replacement repeatedly, one factor of 2 at a time. Works on all positive integers less than 2<sup>65537</sup>.

Comment: Would `x_?EvenQ` work instead of `x_/;EvenQ@x`?

Comment: You're totally right, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 14 bytes

```
{1.5**.lsb*$_}
```

[lsb](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/lsb) returns the position of the least-significant bit, counted from the right. That is, how many trailing zeroes in the binary representation, which is the same as the number of factors of 2. So raise 3/2 to that power and we're done.

```
say {$_*1.5**.lsb}(24);
> 81
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/), <s>139</s> <s>82</s> 71 bytes

*11 bytes saved by ovs.*

```
import data.nat.prime
open list
λx,prod$map(λp,p+1-p%2)$nat.factors x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lNzPv/PzO3IL@oRCElsSRRLy@xRK@gKDM3lSu/IDVPISezuIQrJTVNIc3K9tzuCp2CovwUldzEAo1zuwt0CrQNdQtUjTRVQJrSEpNL8ouKFSr@K6eWJeYoaKQpGGlywdkmSGwjAySOpbnmfwA)

I'm really new to lean so, this answer is probably really inefficient in ways I don't yet know. But it works.

We get a list of factors with `nat.factors` replace `2`s with threes using a `map` and roll it back up with `list.prod`.

Comment: `p+1-p%2` seems to work instead of the conditional expression.

Comment: @ovs Nice.  It's tough to tell what library functions there are and what they are named.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to *Adnan*.

```
ÒDÈ+P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#M7L0Kav8f3iSy@EO7YD/lUqH91spHN6vpPMfAA)

**Explanation**

```
Ò       # push list of prime factors of input
 D      # duplicate
  È     # check each factor for evenness (1 if true, else 0)
   +    # add list of factors and list of comparison results
    P   # product
```

Comment: `ÒDÈ+P` should save a byte

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>7</s>, 6 bytes

```
Yf1Z|p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x@ZZhhVU/D/v5EJAA)

*[1 byte saved thanks to Dennis's genius observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119003/31716)*

---

The best way to explain this is to show the stack at various points.

```
Yf  % Prime factors

[2 2 2 3]

1Z| % Bitwise OR with 1

[3 3 3 3]

p   % Product

81
```

Alternate solution:

```
Yfto~+p
```

Comment: Nice! I had `Yf3H$X>p` for 8 bytes

Answer (score 5):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 9 bytes

```
2/S 3
o@i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@2@kH6xgzJXvkPn/v6ERAA)

Alice has a built-in to replace a divisor of a number with another. I didn't think I'd actually get to make use of it so soon...

Using the code points of characters for I/O, this becomes 6 bytes: `I23SO@`.

#### Explanation

```
2   Push 2 (irrelevant).
/   Reflect to SE. Switch to Ordinal.
i   Read all input as a string.
    The IP bounces up and down, hits the bottom right corner and turns around,
    bounces down again.
i   Try to read more input, but we're at EOF so this pushes an empty string.
/   Reflect to W. Switch to Cardinal.
2   Push 2.
    The IP wraps around to the last column.
3   Push 3.
S   Implicitly discard the empty string and convert the input string to the integer
    value it contains. Then replace the divisor 2 with the divisor 3 in the input.
    This works by multiplying the value by 3/2 as long as it's divisible by 2.
/   Reflect to NW. Switch to Ordinal.
    Immediately bounce off the top boundary. Move SW.   
o   Implicitly convert the result to a string and print it.
    Bounce off the bottom left corner. Move NE.
/   Reflect to S. Switch to Cardinal.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Comment: Your obsession is officially confirmed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/), 38 bytes

```java
int f(int n){return n%2>0?n:f(n/2*3);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#JY5BC4JAFITP@iseQrDbklne2rJf0MljdNhM5YE@ZfdZhPjbbTUGZmDgG6Yfng0WUDTGObgZpHFGYqjE4iRHW/JgCWhzzJIrnSpB@@M2lXqa@z/p2LCPd4cvaD0vcrZI9f1hbO3kGAZVZ9cxvBw0ntNEo1JLH@Rfx2UbdwPHvUe4IYEqgl0GkaLys74RMvZXpNRhMIVe8w8)

---

Previous 43-byte solution:

```java
int f(int n){for(;n%2<1;)n=n/2*3;return n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#JY5BC4JAFITP@iseQrDbkmUeV/sHnTxGh81UHuhTdp9FiL/ddouBGRiYj5nmR4811L1xDq4GadmQGFoRnOTSjlZo2p2LTEsq6Xje59o2PFsC0us2/eeODft4jfiEwUNExRapu92N7Zxc4ihgAhHLTGORnzQqFfqo@jhuhnScOZ38hHsSqBI4XCBR1Lx/l4RM/R8pdRytsdf2BQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <s>112</s> 91 bytes

Grid size 6 (91 bytes)

```
      ? { 2 . . <
     / = { * = \ "
    . & . . . { _ '
   . . { . . } ' * 2
  _ } { / . } & . ! "
 . > % . . < | . . @ |
  \ . . \ . | ~ . . 3
   . . " . } . " . "
    . & . \ = & / 1
     \ = { : = } .
      [ = { { { <
```

Compact version

```
?{2..</={*=\".&...{_'..{..}'*2_}{/.}&.!".>%..<|..@|\..\.|~..3..".}.".".&.\=&/1\={:=}.[={{{<
```

Grid size 7 (112 bytes)

```
       ? { 2 " ' 2 <
      / { * \ / : \ "
     . = . = . = | . 3
    / & / { . . } { . "
   . > $ } { { } / = . 1
  _ . . } . . _ . . & . {
 . > % < . . ~ & . . " . |
  | . . } - " . ' . @ | {
   . . . = & . . * ! . {
    . . . _ . . . _ . =
     > 1 . . . . . < [
      . . . . . . . .
       . . . . . . .
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BDoIwEETv/YqRKCQkloAXYgr6H5IQDkZPeoW0@ut12G2IbXa2ebuzbZ/3eXq8X0uM0HWBR4MMBdUZZRVZiYH5TM2UWnRbBOrJaGsu7Zb7I1naLXrsBXhqJbaahTE1rqrnnOGNGA5wgr4COYkRaArJdBRSMK5kXu@x8iA1lNjptK0y/uVO/9GjTnDdDrcYm/YH)

Compact Version:

```
?{2"'2</{*\/:\".=.=.=|.3/&/{..}{.".>$}{{}/=.1_..}.._..&.{.>%<..~&..".||..}-".'.@|{...=&..*!.{..._..._.=>1.....<[
```

Ungolfed Version for better readability:

[image: Ungolfed]

Approximate Memory Layout

[image]

Grey Path (Memory initialization)

```
?     Read input as integer (Input)
{     Move to memory edge "Divisor left"
2     Set current memory edge to 2 
" '   Move to memory edge "Divisor right" 
2     Set current memory edge to 2
"     Move to memory edge "Multiplier" 
3     Set current memory edge to 3
"     Move to memory edge "Temp 2" 
1     Set current memory edge to 1 
{ { { Move to memory edge "Modulo"
=     Turn memory pointer around 
[     Continue with next instruction pointer
```

Loop entry

```
%     Set "Modulo" to Input mod Divisor
<     Branch depending on result
```

Green Path (value is still divisible by 2)

```
} } {     Move to memory edge "Result"
=         Turn memory pointer around 
*         Set "Result" to "Temp 2" times "Multiplier" (3) 
{ = &     Copy "Result" into "Temp2" 
{ { } } = Move to "Temp"
:         Set "Temp" to Input / Divisor (2)
{ = &     Copy "Temp" back to "Input"
"         Move back to "Modulo"
```

Red Path (value is no longer divisible by 2)

```
} = & " ~ & ' Drag what's left of "Input" along to "Multiplier"
*             Multiply "Multiplier" with "Temp 2"
! @           Output result, exit program
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks, awesome language btw. :)

Comment: Thanks for using it! :) Can't you simplify the memory layout (and thereby the amount of movement you need to do) if you compute `%2` and `:2` both into the "modulo" edge? (So you can just get rid of the top two edges.) And then, could you attach the "multiplier" branch onto the "modulo" edge instead of the "divisor" edge so you need less movement after each branch? (You could possibly even rotate that section, so that "result" or "temp 2" touches "modulo" which would mean you only need to copy the final result once before being able to compute the product.)

Comment: @MartinEnder Uhhhm probably. I'm still getting around the "Agony" part of the language so for now I'll probably stick to making the grid smaller without touching the logic ^^

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 5 bytes

```
Æf3»P

Æf3»P  Main Link, argument is z
Æf     Prime factors
  3»   Takes maximum of 3 and the value for each value in the array
    P  Takes the product of the whole thing
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4Lc340O6A////G1kAAA)

-3 bytes thanks to a hint from @Dennis!

Comment: Hint: **2** is both the only even and the smallest prime number.

Comment: @Dennis I see. Yes, got it now. Thanks! :)

Comment: Congratulations on learning Jelly.

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks! And thanks for teaching it to me. :)

Comment: Congrats on this answer!

Comment: Thanks @EriktheOutgolfer! Thanks for getting me started off with Jelly!

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 23 bytes

```
.+
$*
+`^(1+)\1$
$&$1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#4zI2UNHi0uM6tE1FL4HLyDGBS1XDPeG/njYXUFg7IU7DUFszxlCFS0VNxZDL8P9/AA) Link is to test suite that runs automatically runs all inputs from 1 to 29. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
+`^(1+)\1$
$&$1
```

While the value is even, multiply it by `3/2`.

```
1
```

Convert to decimal.

Note that any FRACTRAN program is trivially convertible to a Retina program with unary I/O. The fraction itself is converted into a match for a string that appears an exact number of times given by the denominator, and the substitution is then `$1` repeated a number of times given by the numerator, although if this is greater than the denominator then `$&` can be used to golf down the code length. It then remains to loop each fraction back to the start of the script, so that the earliest possible fraction is always the next to be substituted. In the case of a single fraction no group is required of course.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
~×₂×₃↰|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@193ePqjpiYQ0fyobUPN//@GRv@jAA)

### How it works

```
~×₂×₃↰|      original program
?~×₂×₃↰.|?.  with implicit input (?) and output (.) added

?~×₂         input "un-multiplied" by 2
    ×₃       multiplied by 3
      ↰      recursion
       .     is the output
        |    or (in case the above fails, meaning that the input
                 cannot be "un-multiplied" by 2)
         ?.  the input is the output
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110721/62131).

Answer (score 4):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), <s>28 27</s> 26 bytes

```
?'2{{(\}}>='!:@=$\%<..>)"*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99e3ai6WiOmttbOVl3RysFWJUbVRk/PTlNJ6/9/IwsA)

Laid out:

```
    ? ' 2 {
   { ( \ } }
  > = ' ! : @
 = $ \ % < . .
  > ) " * . .
   . . . . .
    . . . .
```

This basically runs:

```
num = input()
while num%2 == 0:
    num = (num/2)*3
print num
```

At this point it's an exercise on how torturous I can get the loop path to minimise bytes.

Comment: Well damn, I didn't think of that

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Don't worry, coding anything in Hexagony is an achievement in itself

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - <s>14</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
*^1.5/PQ2
```

Counts the number of 2s in the prime factorization (/PQ2). Multiplies the input by 1.5^(# of 2s)

[Try it](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2a%5E1.5%2FPQ2&input=12&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11&debug=0)

Comment: Interesting approach - too bad it's not as short as the existing Pyth solution.

Comment: @Challenger5 I'm not seeing any other Pyth solution here.

Comment: Oh, OK then. It's a more interesting approach than the typical one for this challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 9 bytes

```
*\?+0+0+0__?\?+?:2
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIqXFw_KzArMCswX18_XFw_Kz86MiIsIlsyOF0iLDBd)

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN (CBQN)](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 30 bytes

```
{0=2|?3×÷2;}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704qTBvwfpH81ekPZq_UuFR2wQFIHtpaUmarsW-agNbo5oPc6eutDc-PB1Id4HYh7cbWYPoWoiibUBtXI8aFgVn5JcruB1aYaj9qG2qkSVEcsECCA0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>15</s> <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
(+2&=)&.q:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#NYyxCoMwFEX3fMUlgzEkPq1bX4mL0KlT104SYo1DpE3/PxXE4cI5w7mSoGY4hoJFB97XEManfdxLbfrK6Yo@XLQQfsohwxEuMIjUX0Xwy4YBtUIz7P26xZR/35jeeDEkI0x@wa3VJ@C4sIRZmkPKHw) Works similar to below, just has different logic concerning replacement of `2` with `3`.

## 15 bytes

```
(2&={,&3)"+&.q:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#NYyxDoIwGAb3PsWXDi1Ny6/C5G/KYuLk5OpEmiJ1gEDdfPhKQhwuuVtOEvQAz9BwOII3asL14e63UjXKf51qjbSKFi5GiNDnmOEJJ1gkas4ihnFGh0qj7rbJe05T/qxpeuHJkIzYhxGXg/kL9oUjDNLuUX4)

### Explanation

```
(2&={,&3)"+&.q:
           &.    "under"; applies the verb on the right, then the left,
                 then the inverse of the right
             q:  prime factors
(       )"+      apply inside on each factor
     ,&3         pair with three: [factor, 3]
 2&=             equality with two: factor == 2
    {            list selection: [factor, 3][factor == 2]
                 gives us 3 for 2 and factor for anything else
           &.q:  under prime factor
```

Comment: Huh, you switched algorithm while I was writing up mine. Now we use the same.

Comment: @Adám Oh, haha. Nice answer! I couldn't resist the opportunity to use `roll` here. :)

Comment: Actually I might be able to save some more bytes...[edit] saved some :D

Comment: Funny you call it Roll, I call it Under. Hope to get it into APL soon.

Comment: @Adám Haha it's actually called under. I got the terms confused

Comment: As in *do this while under the influence of that* Open fridge, take beer, close fridge. Take a beer while the fridge is open.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
[:*/q:+2=q:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@59maxVtpaVfaKVtZFto9f9/mpJBrKF2pp6RpYKfk55CYkFBTqVCmkJ@nkJqYnKGQn4aCJVkpCrkleYmpRYVK6QV5ecqGCqU5CsYWQIA)

`[:` cap (placeholder to call the next verb monadically)

`*/` the product of

`q:` the prime factors

`+` plus (i.e. with one added where)

`2` two

`=` is equal to (each of)

`q:` the prime factors

Comment: I thought you find `[:` disgusting.

Comment: @LeakyNun I do, but I wasn't as clever as [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118994/43319).

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 36 Bytes

```php
for($a=$argn;$a%2<1;)$a*=3/2;echo$a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@ztbD@n5ZfpKGSaAvmW6skqhrZGFprqiRq2RrrG1mnJmfkqyRa//8PAA)

Comment: `for($a=$argn;!1&$a;)$a*=3/2;echo$a;` renaming `$argn` saves a single byte.

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
rimf1f|:*
```

Really simple.

Explanation:

```
ri  e# Read integer:         | 28
mf  e# Prime factors:        | [2 2 7]
1   e# Push 1:               | [2 2 7] 1
f|  e# Bitwise OR with each: | [3 3 7]
:*  e# Product:              | 63
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>19 16 10 9</s> 7 bytes

```
k ®w3Ã×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5@tcGhdufHh5sPT//83NAAA)

## Explanation

```
 k ®   w3Ã ×
Uk mZ{Zw3} r*1
U              # (input)
 k m           # for every prime factor
    Z{Zw3}     # replace it by the maximum of itself and 3
           r*1 # output the product
```

Comment: Hah, JS is tied with Japt. A sure sign there's a much shorter solution ;-)

Comment: Hints: `×` is a shortcut for `r@X*Y}1` (or just `r*1`), which might come in handy. There's also `XwY` which is `Math.max(X,Y)`.

Comment: Thanks, though the recursive solution really is the shortest.

Comment: Nice one! I think you can do `k m_w3Ã×` to save a byte. Also, `m_` can be shortened to `®`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
k mw3 ×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5@tkFturHB4@v//hiYA)

#### Explanation

```
k mw3 ×

k        // Factorize the input.
  mw3    // Map each item X by taking max(X, 3).
      ×  // Take the product of the resulting array.
         // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

Integer output \o/

```
*F+1.|R1P
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aF%2B1.%7CR1P&input=12&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11&debug=0).

### How it works

```
*F+1.|R1P
        P   prime factorization
    .|R1    bitwise OR each element with 1
*F+1        product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 26 bytes

```apl
{⍵(⊣×(3*⊢)×(÷2*⊢))2⍟⍵∨2*⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#RY87DsJADERrOEXKhArP5lvmXIgWoUgr0VEhJGi4QJQD5Ca@SLAnyqZ7sj3z5KXX2@Oiccx1@M7PPJx0@BQG8wRiAY1v2@v9Z4M4Xpelz@Sg8SXHPoNDMAgblA6dQeVQGdTbpHFoDFoHOHXbTs6s9HtZ271ekC6FBnGF0AEeVHuMnpZTmoSx3SWUidtAW@kxSCrD@o0rQBuIZeoFbWCMtsCyJilAW80Ybej@)

This is too verbose, I must be doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1):

## R, 42 bytes

The only right amount of bytes in an answer.

```
x=gmp::factorize(scan());x[x==2]=3;prod(x)
```

Pretty straightforward, uses the `gmp` package to factorize `x`, replaces 2s by 3s, and returns the product.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 20 bytes

```
&>:2%!#v_.@
 ^*3/2 <
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@69mZ2WkqqhcFq/nwKUQp2Wsb6Rg8/@/BQA)

```
& - take in input and add it to the stack
> - move right
: - duplicate the top of the stack
2 - add two to the stack
% - pop 2 and the input off the stack and put input%2 on the stack
! - logical not the top of the stack
# - jump over the next command
_ - horizontal if, if the top of the stack is 0 (i.e. input%2 was non zero) go 
    right, else go left

If Zero:
. - output the top of the stack
@ - end code

If Not Zero:
v - move down
< - move left
2 - add 2 the top of the stack
/ - pop top two, add var/2 to the stack
3 - add 3 to stack
* - pop top two, add var*3 to the stack
^ - move up
> - move right (and start to loop)
```

Comment: [17 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X83Oyki1jEsrTsFBL95I3/j/fwsA "Befunge-93 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```ruby
f=->n{n%2<1?f[n/2*3]:n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5BboMwEEX3nGJkCamtnLYzQAhRSQ5ieUGDUSJFLopBStT07HRsA6tvz/i/59v4/Zimrt4c7K9N6QuPnbIf9Jbpvf2blEIJqGWiSELmM5szl1D5LCQUPrfzvZRQ@txJoHCo5gV@Mik8Rc8MUKTlFTIXAxiZTHFbrA2m7@KM@RgbqwFZgcFB7MhDg3ChkP95IBM7KJ7yhUfsoNhgRxYp5UImdmxjgx1Uaf1umtMZ2h94Xmw/DhLMvTenwbTPBOBm3HgdoIZOha3mGYcDkVILmwP4eEndq4AU1AyIJbmW6xUJRxB945yAPYiuuVyFToxtp38)

A recursive lambda, nothing shocking.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ǐ3v∴Π
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C7%903v%E2%88%B4%CE%A0&inputs=12&header=&footer=)

```
ǐ    # Prime factors
  v∴ # Take max of each and...
 3   # 3
Π    # Take product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 47 bytes

```lisp
(load library
(d F(q((N)(i(odd? N)N(F(*(/ N 2)3
```

Defines a function `F` that takes an integer and returns an integer. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcEhEoAgEAXQ7il@/GtxxGSyEbkDzpadQUGkePr1vWH3V@xt7iw1K4qdPfdvoiLyIZPQWFUPJEmMnLkgIcjmvHJDBNdREXYR/wE)

#### Ungolfed/explanation

The best part is, this uses tail recursion, so it works for arbitrarily large numbers (though it does get horrifically slow).

```lisp
(load library)   ; The library defines the odd?, *, and / functions

(def F           ; Define F to be
 (q              ; a list representing a function
  ((N)           ; that takes one argument, N:
   (if (odd? N)  ; If N is odd
    N            ; just return it
    (F           ; else call F recursively on
     (*          ; the product of
      (/ N 2)    ; N divided by 2
      3))))))    ; with 3
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 1243 bytes

```
Go to Post Office:W 1 L 1 R 1 L.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:S 1 L 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:N 5 L 2 L.[A]Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.2 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:N 1 R 3 L.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Go to Zoom Zoom:W 1 R 3 R.Go to Narrow Path Park:W 1 L 1 L 1 R.Go to Divide and Conquer:E 1 R 2 R.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:E 1 L 1 L 2 L.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Go to Trunkers:S 1 L.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:W 1 L.Switch to plan B if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.3 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:N 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Go to Multiplication Station:W 1 R 2 R 1 R 4 L.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:S 1 R 2 L 2 R.Switch to plan A.[B]Go to Narrow Path Park:N 4 R 1 R 1 L 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:E 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:N 1 L 1 R.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVTBboMwDP0V33ZDKt0u3NoO7dKxCiZNWtVDRgNYTRMawrp@PUsIVF1LYat2IFHi@D372ViRL6yqJwFKwEIUCl6SBGPqvcEI5voLze4sMN6UORDISVFQnlIJqUCeGq/XjMKUfFCWYJFReXAs2Pm1F7WIvWizQ8wEpw1Ic/ICeNC@ro5kOVn1uQdESrGHBVGZXuSml@sRP3FNgfA1zATflVQ6LmABe4LKPCEKIkVknCFbQ1BuqRRMpG2CXSYdqJFsPCBZB7HFfBdiWy@1/gYobCzniR0LZCW1jy5xPb/GcW9S3T9SuAMJ@buSsLtCs0quk@ltF1nyDZVF2ybN0bbHX0is/89Lq4oT7VHFmTHnjHCYAibABeicTsrby/VcMoU5w5goFNzU2uzO@D/a4xZii9ltbHrFrf/VEO4HZOyuddRgzOteORNw4iynqyt9GGjCsB0Ug@n9dlj4g0gnw8q5HF/BMZqqGrnVNw)

Comment: For those wondering what this does: Divide by 2. If that's an integer, multiply the result by 3 and start over. Otherwise, exit the loop and print the result before it was divided by 2.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
ǐ1⋎Π
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLHkDHii47OoCIsIiIsIjI4Il0=)

### How?

```
ǐ1⋎Π
ǐ    # Prime factors
 1⋎  # Bitwise OR each with one
   Π # Product
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors math.unicode`, 28 bytes

```
[ factors """"replace Π ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVdQlJmbWqyXBpYpViguyMksKcnMS4fIluZlJuenpCoUFKWWlFQC1eaVKBSnFpam5iWnFkOUFCXmpQPZ1lxcRpYK0YY6SbH/oxVgxikxKSkxKxWlFuQkJqcqnFugEPs/N7FAQe8/AA)

Note the strings have literal control characters '2' and '3' embedded in them (you can see them on TIO).

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 29 bytes

```
f(n)=1.5^{log_2(gcd(n,2^n))}n
```

A surprisingly short solution, and an interesting usage of \$\operatorname{gcd}()\$.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d0zjbrvswv)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bqjsayo3fg)

It only works for numbers up to 1024 though. Here is a version that should support significantly more numbers at the cost of a few bytes:

#### 42 bytes

```
f(n)=1.5^{log_2(gcd(n,2^{ceil(log_2n)}))}n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
f1Æ|p
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPWYxJUMzJTg2JTdDcCZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTEyJmZsYWdzPQ==)

##### Explanation

```python
f1Æ|p  # Implicit input
f      # Prime factorisation
 1Æ|   # Bitwise OR with 1
    p  # Product of the list
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 5 bytes

```
P1.|B
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyke#@x9gqFfj9P@/oREA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 9 bytes

```
w⌠i1|ⁿ⌡Mπ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@1/@qGdBpmHNo8b9j3oW@p5v@P/f0AgA)

Explanation:

```
w⌠i1|ⁿ⌡Mπ
w          factor into [prime, exponent] pairs
 ⌠i1|ⁿ⌡M   for each pair:
  i          flatten
   1|        prime | 1 (bitwise OR)
     ⁿ       raise to exponent
        π  product
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 23 bytes

```
f(n)=if(n%2,n,f(3*n/2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#@5@mkadpmwkkVY108nTSNIy18vSNNDX/p@UXaeQp2CoY6igYWeooFBRl5pVo5OkoKCno2iko6SiA9AGVAQA)

---

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 23 bytes

```
n->n*1.5^valuation(n,2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#S1ewVfifp2uXp2WoZxpXlphTmliSmZ@nkadjpPk/Lb9IIw@owFBHwchSR6GgKDOvBCijoKSga6egpKOQrpGnqan5HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 23 bytes

```c
f(n){n=n&1?n:f(n/2*3);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYnNCoMwEAbPyVN8CMquP1TrzVR9kV5KJLIHtyLexGdP09MwM75ZvY8xkPKloxbdrEOSx7Ps2d1R9MT2ESW2lzXhe4D@STCicwkv9G1iVbE1Zj/SC5TlC5oJ@fLWrIbUCCTMzt7xBw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip) `-z`, 123 bytes

```
tv~S
a^v.bv.cv.dv.ev.fv.gv.
 zLxzLxzLxzLxzLxzLxzLxz-vh
A##L##L##L##L##L##L##L##'
B))L))L))L))L))L))L))'
   C  D  E  F  G  H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9LC4JAGEX38ysuakxCflJrCXpoLYQW7QPTMaXXkNOXPf@6PVZBweFs7ubcZVIVTZoY9GFUZSgtSo0ggAxnkWwMP@YiWTAtmVKmjEkx5UwrJoFLXP/B40IMbDv@hxRD141/kALACBgDIRABE2DavAKEeJc5eblRuCE5rSGv@lDuTN62WqnVcbruXb4Wf6@N/y7/iPQZ3uXrzg2FqrPjVsNTkH4XViuzZNPrPQE) (Includes a bashy wrapper for numeric conversion).

#### Explanation

This solution uses Chip's 'native' data type, an unsigned 8-bit integer. Any input or output that would be outside the bounds of that type will produce undefined results.

I and O are done via raw bytes values, hence the wrapper in the TIO.

The algorithm, in C-ish looks something like this:

```
uchar byte = in();
while(!(byte & 0x1)) {
  byte += byte>>1; // logical shift
}
out(byte);
```

The bulk of this program are the eight full adders (`##`) and their wiring (`L`, `)`, `x`, ...).

To see all steps of the computation, delete the `S`. You may want to adjust the hexdump format to `"%d\n"` for nicer output.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
function(x){while(!x%%2)x=x/2*3;x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pflFqQk5icGl9Snl8cX55ZkhFfklGUmlps@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCs7o8IzMnVUOxQlXVSLPCtkLfSMvYuqL2f3FiQUFOpYahlZGlDi6DNP8DAA)

**Or: recursive version** (same bytes)

```r
f=function(x)`if`(x%%2,x,f(x/2*3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dczRCYAgEADQaQQvhMi@CpxFRU4UREUNr@ltgt4Ar62GNVmHeszS9Ywj6BEaYlfLK/9kN2LJnMBEbzgxJgUJz2mX2wmwuq01vfy45SX@Ilgf)

2 is the only even prime number, so we divide the input by 2 and multiply by 3 until it's no longer even.

---

*Edit: now reading the other answers, this approach has already been used many times in other languages...*

Answer (score 0):

## [Assembly (NASM, 32-bit, Linux)](https://www.nasm.us/), 57 bytes

```
mov ebx,3
l:mul ebx
rcr eax,1
jnc l
rcl eax,1
div ebx
ret
```

[Try it online!](https://jdoodle.com/ia/hIP)

Both, the input and the output are in the `eax` register.

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 20 bytes (5 instrs)

```
00000000: 4e000004 3f000001 1b000003 4f00fffe  N¡¡¥?¡¡¢ñ¡¡¤O¡”“
00000010: f8010000                             ẏ¢¡¡
```

```
r23 BEV  $0,1F      // if(!(i & 1)) goto end
0H  SRU  $0,$0,1    // loop: i >>= 1
    MULU $0,$0,3    // i *= 3
    BEV  $0,0B      // if(!(i & 1)) goto loop
1H  POP  1,0        // return i
```

If it could be guaranteed the number was even, it could be cut down to four instructions (the first instruction is just to avoid halving if already odd).