# Minimal distinct character quine

Tags: code-challenge, quine

Your challenge is to construct a [*proper*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine) [quine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Quine) using as few *distinct* characters as possible.

### Scoring

Your score is equal to the number of distinct characters in your code, aiming to minimise this. [Standard quine rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12357/66833) apply.

Comment: [unary quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198585/68942) wins this lol

Comment: Runner up: Ørjan Johansen's [`///` quine](https://esolangs.org/wiki////#Quines) using only `/` and ```\```

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 9 distinct characters, 15341 bytes

```python
exec('%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+'%c'%(+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7doxDoMwDIXh0yBATFWPhJA6tR06lNOnl6AQ25@yR/4dx3l5yXv/PF7Pe2vbd1uncVjHYVpuV495uTqSIyOoMFfPowpnbtYKq1ipUv/Jmy@Pqh9PLxHYXbgROR/Pzb2Yz6zxzB2xRrd3E8QY0T86ftYIM@artcrrGMelpapyZYe2wUrZ5F2zOJ01Rg4ydhJnANY6PZLPgbHfzPnJ5OYpq/y5qB1Gxctq7N3ojwNuRJw9b1pcUK4t15aGoscQ4abHKIyi6mlu7Qc)

This encodes each character as a series of `+1`s and then sums them all together before executing the final encoded program:

```python
A="""print(end='exec('+'+'.join("'%%c'%%("+'+1'*ord(B)+")"for B in'A=""'+'"'+%r+'"'+'"";exec(A%%A)')+")")""";exec(A%A)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCoQwDER/RQZCkhWEZY@Lh/orWrF7SKV40K/vxl5kGAaGx9uvY8v2qTWMAPaS7JBoy8jxjLNw7xl@OZmAiWavwL83v3JZZNIeijWXbuqS8a1w3kulDQPf5glEQbnRiucMWusf)

Comment: Impressive! Is the trailing newline needed?

Comment: @Recursive Co. I guess it's to account for the extra newline printed, but `print(end=...)` or `print(...,end='')` should fix that?

Comment: I think that since [7 characters are enough for universality](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110722/20260), that should allow making a quine.

Comment: @dingledooper Ah I completely forgot about the newline. Yes I'll remove that soon

Comment: @xnor That's Python 2, Python 3 needs the `()`s. I looked into doing Py2, but I couldn't figure out a way without the code blowing up to unmanageable levels

Comment: For Python 2, I'm pretty sure it is possible to "easily" with 8 by removing parenthesis, and using `"%c%%c%%%%c"%-~...-~0%-~...-~0-~...-~0` to construct the string.

Comment: For the trailing newline, if you don't mind about errors, you can replace `print(end=...)` by `input(...)` wich prints to stdout without the trailing newline (the only thing is that it will throw an EOFError). It also saves 770 bytes

Answer (score 9):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 3 distinct characters, 1432 bytes

```
111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--11-11-p111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--111-p111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--11-111-1--p111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--1111-1--p111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--111-1--111-1--p111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--111-1-1--111-1--p111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--111-1-1-1--111-1--p111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--11-1p111-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1--11p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39DQUJdyqAsyxVC3gDqm4bWHDrbg8yOYRRd/0semwQFhATuyfE0gNAY8PHQR1o6YmAHn8gH2JdANBf//AwA)

This uses the characters `1-p` to `p`ut this code at the start of the program:

```
"/
o<
:/r~:
```

This quotes the whole program, accounts for the characters that were overwritten, and then outputs the program itself.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), Score 13, 523 bytes

```hs
p=putStr;main=a>>mmm>>a>>mmm>>mmmm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmmmm>>mmm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mm>>mm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mm>>mm>>mm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mm>>mm>>mm>>mm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmmmm>>mmmmmm>>mmm;a=p"p=putStr;main=a>>mmm>>a>>mmm>>mmmm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmmmm>>mmm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mm>>mm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mm>>mm>>mm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmm>>mm>>mm>>mm>>mm>>mmmmm>>mmm>>mmmmmm>>mmmmmm>>mmm;a=p";mm=p"m";mmm=p"\"";mmmm=p";m";mmmmm=p"m=p";mmmmmm=p"\\"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v8C2oLQkuKTIOjcxM8820c4uNzfXzg5G58LJXLgImhS6NCoHVR2mWhyKsBiKRyVOJ8Bo60TbAqWR41Pr3FwgmQuiQYwYJTArFywDYYLlISqhvJgYpf//AQ)

The used characters are:

```hs
p=utSr;main>"\
```

Comment: mmmmmmmmm, yum!

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes, 4 distinct characters

```
≔´θ´´´≔´´´´´⪫´θ´´´´´θθ´≔´´⪫θ´´θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R55RDW87tOLQFBMEcGHy0ajVCBgTP7QDxoGqAshC5czv@/wcA) Explanation: I started with the standard Charcoal quine from [Golf you a quine for great good!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/) (which uses six distinct characters) and adapted it to try to remove the `Ｆ`, `⁺` and `ι` characters, which I was able to do at the cost of having to use the `⪫` character instead. I was then amused to discover that in fact the final quine was the same length as the original quine (less the trailing newline, which was needed for a true quine in the then version of Charcoal that used `Ａ` instead of `≔`).

Comment: Nice - we're tied for length (not that that matters, but still).

Comment: might be worth linking the [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/121529#121529) directly for the standard quine

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 31 bytes, score: 8 distinct bytes

```ruby
$;="$;=%p;$><<$;%%$;";$><<$;%$;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XaVgmIVQusVexsbFSsVVVVrJVgbBXr//8B)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes, 2 distinct bytes

```
”ṘṘ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw9yHO2cA0f//AA)

### How it works

This is the [standard Jelly quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/73930#73930), nothing too interesting

```
”ṘṘ - Main link. Takes no arguments
”Ṙ  - Yield the character "Ṙ"
  Ṙ - Convert to a Jelly representation ("Ṙ" -> ”Ṙ) and print
    - Implicitly output the character "Ṙ"
```

Comment: maybe we  should have a thread for quines from the main question which are also optimal here.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 11 distinct bytes

```python
p='p=%r;print(p%%p)';print(p%p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8BWvcBWtci6oCgzr0SjQFW1QFMdzinQ/P8fAA)

Nice. Uses p and r as variables because print is necessary, so why not just use the characters from there? 31 bytes in length if that's a tiebreaker.

I don't see this being improved on, given TC Python 3 is already <s>7</s> 8 characters.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 10 distinct bytes

```python
p='p=%r;print p%%p';print p%p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8BWvcBWtci6oCgzr0ShQFW1QB3OLvj/HwA)

What I do see, however, is that Recursive Co. has gotten a 10 byte answer, which, again, is 3 from optimal. Go upvote their answers as well!

Comment: Uh, wouldn't that mean 7 bytes is a lower bound then?

Comment: Yes. Yes it does.

Comment: so, you mean it *can* be improved on right? also, python 3 is TC in ~8~ *9* chars, python 2 is 7

Comment: It CAN, but realistically, it most likely won't be given I'm 3 from optimal

Comment: [Python 2: uses spaces instead of `()`](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8BWvcBWtci6oCgzr0ShQFW1QB3OLvj/HwA)

Comment: @RecursiveCo. Cool - is it okay if I add that to this answer?

Comment: Sure, if you like!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript console (<s>9 8</s> 7 distinct characters, <s>21 22</s> 24 bytes)

```javascript
($=$=>'($='+$+')($)')($)
```

Thanks to JoKing, again for -1 byte!

Older versions

```javascript
($=_=>`($=`+$+`)()`)() // 8 distinct characters
($=_=>`($=${$})()`)() // 9 distinct characters
```

Comment: You can also shorten this to 7 bytes `($=$=>'($='+$+')($)')($)` (lol)

Comment: Thanks @JoKing! i got the 8 distinct character version seconds before you posted.

Comment: Is this a valid 6 byte? `$=>\`${$}\`\`$\``

Comment: @James No, that doesn't follow the proper quine rules that one part of the program should encode another. It's basically equivalent to `$=>$`

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes 8 distinct bytes

```ruby
p="p=%p;$><<p%%p";$><<p%p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8BWqcBWtcBaxc7GpkBVtUAJyir4/x8A)

Thanks to Jo King for -1 distinct byte

Comment: Pretty trivial to get to [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8BWqcBWtcBaxc7GpkBVtUAJyir4/x8A). Pity you can't reuse `p` as the output function though

Comment: @JoKing dammit, just as I posted my score 8 answer!

Comment: @JoKing, afaik, you actually can use p as the output function, even after defining it as a variable. e.g: https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DBVsGUq0Ch4P9/AA i dont think its relevant here though, as p would output the string with quotes

Comment: i meant that it can't be used in a quine context which would have been neat

Comment: Ah i get what you mean. Thanks for the -1 bytes anyways!

Answer (score 2):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein), score 6, 71 bytes

```
<22+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+@+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+2+22<"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/9/GyEgbP3QgIG9kZKPE9f//fwMDg/@6jgA)

Uses the characters `<2+@"` and newline.  This uses `"` to push all the rest of the program backwards.  However since this portion of the program is a palindrome, there is no need to put it in the correct order.  All we have to do is add `"` onto the end.  This is done by adding a whole bunch of `2`s up to 34.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), score 21, 64 bytes

```c
main(s){printf(s="main(s){printf(s=%c%s%c,34,s,34);}",34,s,34);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPo1izuqAoM68kTaPYVglDRDVZtVg1WcfYRKcYSGha1yohsf//BwA)

[Standard C quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/122856#122856), except not using the `%1$c` since that's extra chars.

#### Breakdown

- `main(,){";}` (11) are probably required
- `printf` (+5=16) is required for most standard quines
- `%cs` (+3=19) from the format string
- `34` (+2=21), the ASCII code for the double quote. I don't believe hexadecimal or octal will be better here

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) for Linux x86_64, score 13, <s>8241</s> 7604 bytes

```c
main[]={+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+11+11+1+1,+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1,+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+11+11,+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+1,+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+1,+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+111+111+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1,+1111111111+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+11+1+1+1+1+1,+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+1111111+1111+111+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,+111111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,+1111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1,+1111111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+111+111,+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+1+1+1+1+1+1,+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+1+1+1+1+1+1,+1111111111,+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+1+1+1,+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+1+1,+1111111111+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1,+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+1+1+1,+1111111111+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+1,+1111111111+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+1+1,+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1,+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1,+1111111111+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+111+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1,+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+11+11+1,+1111111111+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1+1+1,+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1,+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+11+1+1+1+1,+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1+1,+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+111+1+1,+1111111111+1111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+111111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+11111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+1111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+111111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+11111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+1111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+111+11+11+11+11+11+11+1+1+1,1};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7Vm7DsIwDPwgp0NmxJcghioqFeKxlAGB@HVCeQyVmqdjJ6lEaZouleKLfXcxqumV0vrU7s@b7foOcrxsj98w3fOf@Hz2vQD/Rv0C0wn1NGIyAUIARdyRqETO/gkJhxEYV@JwoQbRmIWBAe4x3lVHwrPXHlT@iDgQoS9@vpj9tWxnfkmjBxk1goBMaQVmTjbEYut8m67ILf6CQbGIStKKqyUcI7Bl0oyuhHHejXP9vq18D@IcJ0UzTQ1kgHGu10s695kSDFbRTOLt9Azw6@eSlTK8yF2sjPIVLPGlOKxUojAzd5FDZ2Fw4@HMaVRzOQF0UiVG7wmCgymna67E4Ue1O6B2gqdUfkRfBeHVSUo6TdbQFhLCTlWIbOHY/Hiizd4H4IubUI5CJN7fZc99SOAWf8yhEIXiksHjpmPGVigm//O1tkqnd7gciPQ/vcj0qvJCYjApRYrBTGHysdL6qXbHth90c@uunRourTq8AA)

This uses the characters `aimn[]={}+1,;`

Bootstrap program:

```c
.text
.section .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.globl main
.type main, @function
main:
.cfi_startproc
call poprbp
.ascii "main[]={,+1111111111};"
poprbp:
pop %rsi
lea -5(%rsi),%rbp
lea 119(%rsi),%r8
push %rdi
pop %rax
push $8
pop %rdx
syscall
add $9, %rsi
push:
mov 0(%rbp),%r12d
push $11
pop %r13
mov $1111111111,%ebx
push $10
pop %r14
cmp:
cmp %r12d, %ebx
jbe movslq
xchg %ebx, %eax
xor %edx, %edx
dec %r13d
div %r14d
xchg %eax, %ebx
jmp cmp
movslq:
movslq %r13d, %rdx
ones:
push %rdi
pop %rax
syscall
sub %ebx,%r12d
jne cmp
comma:
dec %rsi
push %rdi
pop %rax
push %rdi
pop %rdx
syscall
inc %rsi
add $4, %rbp
cmp %r8, %rbp
jne push
theend:
add $10, %rsi
push $3
pop %rdx
syscall
ret
.cfi_endproc
.size main, .-main
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLraoMwFP7vUwSxoMwOs3ZgLXuSdYSYhJribaYtjtJnd7l4OZTR@cdzyXc5J2HrI2PDUFFZh9HNI4SqihBEyLUp6VmWgpDQ8xktS9Q2bZe3h9r3/FeqmJTo4Bvc59fHLX7B83ffH3x7ygGyKUarTkmblIKi9Xto8iheTaSmivFuLqcOeFGFRnIJaGi/tIIUNLhrqB9lHNuYco6CXbyIG5TzVDVXlIRG38jhNw5YMQa0eDOfD5Y545XIoRGcQMjWJqwa59cBshrayQQ75QJpTlV@27RnxdE2zZFxxL7pdMJtaRyOC2YtObdcXq0ahxS0hypaWatPE2i1DMSOKl5219RCZf9tHi5YXXLnelnhqRazJGuqimbAObiGZ/f60PrjZmUN6Ow1b80c42tyC09Bxbgy1DY5F0LUPFuwOHl4IyjYPNfvxNn8o713H4Zf)

This was based on the following C program.

```c
#include<unistd.h>
main(){
  write(1,"main[]={",8);
  int i = 0;
  do {
    unsigned int x = 1111111111;
    unsigned int y = ((unsigned int*)main)[i];
    do {
      while( y<x ) {
        x/=10;
      } 
      printf("+%d",x);
    }
    while(y-=x);
    write(1,",",1);
  } while ( i++<10 ); 
  write(1,"1};",3);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBRC4IwFIXf/RWHRbCllaOXYNofER/CmV6oFaWkxH67zTQT2l52z/k4995l6yLLum5BJjvXOo9qQ49Kb8qDdzmS4eLlAc87VTmXAeulJI1fLNgL5QwyFQgxwr7QV/QwUJsHFSbXH7txtpyO@gdaB3A@l1ai7yMSSgd8CnaTlHTOOdqogZhEoNnGMlRjaTE@bncXduLMX2oWNGLwrffLadfxV55WdFd@NDtA4CDfj2QIoTD/C2kVC3YOtV33Bg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 18 distinct bytes

```perl
$_=q(print"\$_=q($_);eval;");eval;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rZQo6AoM69EKQbMVonXtE4tS8yxVoLS//8DAA)

This is a classic Perl quine. I have no idea how Perl works, but this is tested on TIO. Feel free to tell me how to improve this. 34 bytes if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 distinct bytes, 4 bytes

```
`I`I
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJgSWBJIiwiIiwiIl0=)

classic vyxal quine